# Php INTL format currency

Tags: php, currency, intl

This code:

```
$formatter = new \NumberFormatter('ar', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo $formatter->formatCurrency(1234.99, 'EUR'), PHP_EOL;
```

outputs:

```
€ ١٬٢٣٤٫٩٩
```

Is there any way to make formatCurrenct to output

```
EUR ١٬٢٣٤٫٩٩
```

and still would be nice if ISO symbols would be translated.. so if i pass YER as a currency, I want to get something like this:

```
 ر.ي.‏ ١٬٢٣٥
```

Comment: Passing `'YER'` as currency gives me `ر.ي.‏ ١٬٢٣٥` … so what exactly is your question regarding this?